# Is there an alternative way for nested try and catch?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

In the below posted code, I am tring to code a utility method and I want to check if an object is null or not and a string is null and not empty.
so, I coded the way shown below with throwing some exception, but I think the code could have been coded in a better way because the way I coded it has nested
try and catch blocks.and i do not think it is a good style

please guide me to better code the belwo method

**code**:

```
public static boolean isFragmentShowing(Activity activity, String tag) throws Exception {

    try {
        if (activity != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = FragmentUtils.getFragmentManagerInstance(activity);

            try {
                if (tag != null && !tag.equals("")) {
                    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

                    return (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())? true : false;

                } else {
                    throw new NullPointerException("isFragmentShowing: fragment tag passed is null or empty");
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
                System.exit(1);
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("isFragmentShowing: context reference is null");
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        System.exit(1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother catching the exception if you’re going to catch it in the outer block?

Comment: It seems all you are doing is catching NPE. why don't just catch any NPE at the end. I don't actually catch NPE, Rather I check NPE

Comment: @Yohannes can you please provide some code

Comment: Nested `try` / `catch` is not inherently a style problem, but your particular code is indeed hinky.  You are *conditionally* throwing NPEs, and then immediately catching them.  Why `throw` at all, then?  You could achieve the same behavior by executing the body of the appropriate `catch` block  instead of throwing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you please provide some code

Comment: Remove the inner `try...catch`; done. Then maybe delete the rest of the code... calling `System.exit` is always a bad idea. Why catch anything? In this example it make absolutely no difference - just let the stack unwind.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i would appreciate it if you provided some code please

Comment: Okay. Code provided! :)

Comment: Note that `condition ? true : false` is simply a more verbose way of writing `condition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two part of your application. One is request validation and another one is application logic. Separate request validation and application logic. It will be easier to read and maintains. Here is my try in bellow

```
public static boolean isFragmentShowing(Activity activity, String tag) throws Exception {

//validate request 
if(activity == null) {
    // throw exception or return value 
}   
if (tag == null && tag.equals("")){
    // throw exception or return value 
}
// rest of the part
FragmentManager fragmentManager = FragmentUtils.getFragmentManagerInstance(activity);
Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
return (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're going to do with the exception is

```
Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage().toString());
```

then you don't need the exception, you just need a string. As I said on your previous question, catching `NullPointerException` is rarely the correct thing to do; more generally, using exceptions for control flow is a pretty dubious practice. And using `System.exit` is rarely what you really want to do.

You can create a method something like:

```
boolean logMessageAndExit(String message) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + message);
  System.exit(1);
  return false;
}
```

and then call in your code like this:

```
if (activity == null) {
  return logMessageAndExit("isFragmentShowing: context reference is null");
}
if (tag != null && !tag.equals("")) {
  return logMessageAndExit("isFragmentShowing: fragment tag passed is null or empty");
}

Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
return fragment != null && fragment.isVisible();
```

Returning a boolean here is a mere convenience to allow you to `return` it: this convinces the compiler that execution never goes past that line, even though the `return` is never really executed.

(You could make it return something `Throwable` instead, so you can `throw logMessageAndExit`, to make it more clear that it is abnormal).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's how your `isFragmentShowing` method should be like.
You see I've removed ALL of the `try/catches`. This is because your method already `throws` a checked `Exception` and the code calling your static method would need to wrap the call to `isFragmentShowing` inside the `try/catch` none the less. You can catch the NPE there quite easily and even print out its stack trace which would let you know which instance was essentially `null`. Either `fragment` or `activity`. 
The only time we need to actually throw an NPE is when `tag.equals("")` returns `true` (since that won't throw an exception). 
I've also replaced the last ternary operator return by just `fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()` since it means the same thing (`true` is returned if the expression evaluates to `true` and `false` on the right is returned otherwise, why not the return the result of the expression itself?)

And here's the code:

```
public static boolean isFragmentShowing(Activity activity, String tag) throws Exception {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = FragmentUtils.getFragmentManagerInstance(activity);

    if (tag.equals("")) {
        throw new NullPointerException("isFragmentShowing: fragment tag passed is empty");
    }

    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    return fragment != null && fragment.isVisible();
}
```